# C# datagridview setting cell value stays null

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm dynamically adding rows to a datagridview this way:

```
Question question = new Question();
List<Question> questions = question.GetQuestionsByQuestionnaire(questionnaireId);
if (questions != null)
{
    dgvQuestions.Columns.Add("Question", "Vraag");
    dgvQuestions.Columns.Add("QuestionType", "Vraag type");
    dgvQuestions.Columns.Add("Category", "Categorie");

    for (int i = 0; i < questions.Count; i++ )
    {
        int row = dgvQuestions.Rows.Add();

        dgvQuestions.Rows[row].Cells["Question"].Value = questions[i].Question;
        dgvQuestions.Rows[row].Cells["QuestionType"].Value = questions[i].QuestionType;
        dgvQuestions.Rows[row].Cells["Category"].Value = questions[i].Category;

        dgvQuestions.Rows[row].Tag = questions[i];
    }
}
```

I don't get any errors, but the cell value stays null and I'm 100% sure that Question, QuestionType and Category contains data. What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about why this is the case, but I'd go for a mix of dynamic data but typed dataset.

What you'd do is:

1. Create a typed `DataSet`, add a "Questions" table with the columns you need
2. Put an instance of your `DataSet` from the Toolbox on your form (must recompile before that), name it for example `myDataSource`.
3. Put a `BindingSource` on your form, assign the `myDataSource` to the `DataSource` property and select your table for the `DataMember` property.
4. Assign the binding source to the `DataSource` property of your `DataGridView`

Add data to the data source by using for example `myDataSource.Questions.NewQuestionsRow()` and `myDataSource.Questions.AddQuestionsRow(...)`.

Comment: Thnx, but what I want is to set the Tag property for each row. Otherwise I could use the BindingList as a datasource.

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered something similar.  You might want to make sure EnableViewState is set to True for your GridView.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure VitualMode is set to False for your GridView.